# TRIAC driver circuit - MOC3021

Tags: circuit-design, triac, dimmer

I have created a TRIAC AC dimmer circuit using an MOC3021 and I am facing the problem that the output is always on.

Please help me rectify the issue.

Please see the image of the circuit and Zero PCB I have attached.

**Circuit Diagram**
[image]

**Zero PCB I am testing with:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the Triac is not shorted? If not already, make sure that power is not connected (both N and L), and using a multimeter, check if L is shorted to load before checking the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Prince Phillip would turn in his grave looking at your clearances on mains

Comment: Sure just checked this out. Seems like resistor network given by MOC does not work. I changed it to 150 and 2.2k and it worked beautifully.

PS: I know about the clearance, I am just a daredevil 

Answer (score 1):

Just checked it out. Resistor network was an issue. It got cleared. Resistor given by MOC does not work. I needed to use 150 ohm and 2.2k ohm